# Grab query string value from URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to visit https://example.com/?GCLID=test123 and store whatever is in GCLID in a variable.

How do I do this? The following keeps returning *null*

```js
var url = window.location.href;

// test
url = "https://example.com/?GCLID=test123";

const params = new URLSearchParams(url);
var gclid = params.get('GCLID');

alert(params);
alert(gclid);
```

Comment: You may have to search only the query portion of the URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take the part after '?' in new URLSearchParams, see below
example for same, i.e you will pass window.location.search like this

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
```

```js
var url = window.location.href;

// test
url = "https://example.com/?GCLID=test123";

const params = new URLSearchParams(url.split('?')[1]);
var gclid = params.get('GCLID');

alert(params);
alert(gclid);
```